# SQL where clause depends on a prevoius select statement

Tags: mysql

In the following statement, I am trying to retrieve tweets and their authors information from a database. I also want to retrieve hashtags that are related to those tweets (in other words, mentioned in those tweets).

```
select Tweet.Label, Tweet.TDate, Author.Lable, Author.ALink, Tweet.TLink, Tweet.ID as TID 
from Tweet, Author
where Tweet.ID IN 
(select TweetID from TweetMention where MentionID IN 
(select ID from Mention where Label = 'Cr7Prince4ever')) 
AND Author.ID = Tweet.AuthorID
UNION
select Label, HLink
from Hashtag
where ID IN
(select HashID from TweetHashs where TweetID = TID)
```

Everything is working fine except that how to link between Tweet and Hashtag. I want first to retrieve tweets and their authors and based on the retrieved tweets retrieve hashtags written in these tweets. Currently, the error that I couldn't fix is in the second select statement in the where clause `where TweetID = TID`. I tried to let the second statement gets the tweet ID based on the retrieved tweet ID in the first statement but it didn't work.

Comment: Please firstly specify is it sql-server or mysql. sql-server is Microsoft SQL Server not generic SQL Servers. Secondly, specify the version of database you are using.

Comment: Let me count a few things wrong:  (1) you have two totally unrelated databases as tags; (2) you are using antiquated join syntax (commas in the `from` clause should be forbidden); (3) you are doing a `union` on two subqueries that have different columns; (4) you are, presumably, attempting to use a column alias in a `where` clause (`TID`).  I would suggest that you delete this question and ask another question with sample data, desired results, a clear explanation of what you want, and no claims that a broken query "is working fine".

Answer (score 0):

Your query has many issues, and cannot work.

Maybe you are looking for a query like this:

```
select     Tweet.Label, 
           Tweet.TDate, 
           Author.Lable, 
           Author.ALink, 
           Tweet.TLink, 
           Tweet.ID,
           Hashtag.Label,
           Hashtag.HLink           
from       Tweet
inner join Author 
        on Tweet.AuhtorID = Author.ID
left join  TweetHashs 
        on TweetHashs.TweetID = Tweet.ID
left join  Hashtag 
        on Hashtag.ID = TweetHashs.HashID 
where      Tweet.ID IN 
           (   select TweetID 
               from   TweetMention 
               where  MentionID IN
                      (  select ID 
                         from   Mention 
                         where  Label = 'Cr7Prince4ever'
                       )
            )
```

NB: The spelling of *TweetHashs* seems wrong, but this is how you put it.

The above query will return multiple results for the same tweet, as it lists every hash for a tweet in a separate row. If you prefer to have only one result per tweet, and have their hashes concatenated in one comma-separated list, you could use `group_concat` with `group by`:

```
select     Tweet.Label, 
           Tweet.TDate, 
           Author.Lable, 
           Author.ALink, 
           Tweet.TLink, 
           Tweet.ID,
           group_concat(Hashtag.Label) labels,
           group_concat(Hashtag.HLink) links           
from       Tweet
inner join Author 
        on Tweet.AuhtorID = Author.ID
left join  TweetHashs 
        on TweetHashs.TweetID = Tweet.ID
left join  Hashtag 
        on Hashtag.ID = TweetHashs.HashID 
where      Tweet.ID IN 
           (   select TweetID 
               from   TweetMention 
               where  MentionID IN
                      (  select ID 
                         from   Mention 
                         where  Label = 'Cr7Prince4ever'
                       )
            )
group by   Tweet.ID
```

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave a comment?